# Are diodes (or FETs) electrets?

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, dielectric

The explanations I see of diodes and FETs seem to involve various depletion regions, migration of electrons and holes, and the such. My (perhaps naive) interpretation of these explanations implies that there is persistent charge separation in such semiconductor devices. Am I correct, and is it therefore proper to refer to diodes as a form of [electret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret)?

Comment: I think that considering a diode as a form of an electret is extremely limiting. There are too many differences between what is going on with the structural charge separation in, e.g. quartz (electret) and the redistribution of electron-hole pairs in a semiconductor. At the very least, an electret has no analogue to the Shockley-Reid-Hall equation. Without SRH, you absolutely cannot understand semiconductor devices.